# What language is this - often used on code golf

Tags: discussion, support

I've seen a couple of questions which use a language which has the following chracters:

`<>-+.[]`

What language is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite possibly [BrainF_ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) ([concerning the spelling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24079/2509)), a minimal programing language and a exemplar of the [Turing Tar Pit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit).

Comment: thanks - I found this out just before you posted by searching strange programming languages into google :)

Answer (score 1):

Fish and GolfScript are also contenders.... J is also possible.
I've seen a lot of GolfScript because it allows for concise manipulation of arrays and such.
Fish uses the above characters much more extensively than the others.... and I confess I don't know exactly what distinguishes J syntactically.

I believe that all of them fall into the category of the [Turing Tar Pit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit) as described by @dmckee

Comment: Since BF is fairly easy to implement, a relatively easy way to show that a language is turing complete is to implement BF. I think the OP is asking about BF, because the other languages you mention here use other characters as well whereas BF uses only those 7

Comment: Interesting comment... I hadn't though of such a proof by implementation... I may have to try that this weekend.

Comment: J is definitely not a turing tar pit, though it looks like one. Turing tar pits tend to have a small number of unhelpful operations with very short names, whereas J has a large number of extremely helpful operations with very short names. (or [no names](http://jsoftware.com/help/jforc/forks_hooks_and_compound_adv.htm).) Thus the confusion.

Comment: gnibbler: BF has eight instructions, but `,` was not mentioned in the list in the question.